# Script Time Out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

My script is timing out, I'm just looking for some ideas anyone has to optimise the script so that it runs faster. Note there are several email addresses that I need to bring the data across from.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet() {
  var obj = [{ mycal: "Email", sheetName: "a" },{ mycal: "Email", sheetName: "b"  },{ mycal: "Email", sheetName: "c"  },{ mmycal: "Email", sheetName: "d"  },{ mycal: "email", sheetName: "e" },{ mycal: "email", sheetName: "f" }];
  var colors = Calendar.Colors.get().calendar;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  obj.forEach(({ mycal, sheetName }) => {
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("July 01, 2022 00:00:00 UTC"), new Date("June 30, 2023 00:00:00 UTC"));
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.clearContents();
    var calColor = cal.getColor();
    var header = ["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", "Color"];
    var offset = 6;
    var { v, c } = events.reverse().reduce((o, e, i) => {
      var color = e.getColor();
      var row = offset + i + 1;
      var c = colors[color] ? colors[color].background : calColor;
      var f = `=(HOUR(F${row})+(MINUTE(F${row})/60))-(HOUR(E${row})+(MINUTE(E${row})/60))`;
      o.v.push([mycal, events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), f, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), c]);
      o.c.push([c]);
      return o;
    }, { v: [], c: [] });
    var values = [header, ...v];
    sheet.getRange(6, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    sheet.getRange(7, 7, v.length - 1).setNumberFormat('.00');
    sheet.getRange(7, 15, c.length).setBackgrounds(c);
  });
}
```

Comment: I'd consider not doing it for an entire year.   How many events is that?

Comment: Thousands - I know, I thought of doing the same, but I need all the data over as the calendar is my timesheet program that records all staff time so I can bill everything correctly etc. I could reduce the columns - I don't need 15 columns, but every time I do it gives me an error - I will ask about that on a separate question, just seeing if there is a formatting thing I can change.

Comment: Then I would consider doing it in batches of maybe one quarter at a time.  You may have to modify how you output the data using sheet.getLastRow()

Comment: Do you think there will be a clash if there are several "export_gcal_to_gsheet()" functions running at the same time - even though they are grabbing different data periods?

Comment: Every function in a project must have a unique name

Comment: I would use the same function and let the dates be a  parameter (perhaps an object).

Comment: Excellent - thank you, I have no idea how to do any if that though - but thank you for you your direction - I will do some research.

Comment: You could also do it for one sheet at a time perhaps

Comment: I'd be happy with that - how do I do that without out each function having the same name?

Comment: Why are you having so much difficulty with the idea that all functions requiring unique names?  That's no different than client side Javasscript.

Comment: Because I tried it earlier by splitting up the functions to do 3 staff each under a different file name in the same script editor and it came up with a warning (when I was setting up a trigger based on Time "This project contains one or more functions with the same name. Choosing one of these functions will result in undefined behaviour and sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't" it was all over the place.

Comment: In my experience it always  picks the first one that's loaded and disregards the rest whenever that function name is called.  So it's pointless to give functions identical names.

Comment: Yep that's the problem I have - I split the two scripts and it's only running the first one.  This is why I feel I can't run two functions with the same name.